# Decomposition of Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $E$ be the splitting field a (not necessarily irreducible) polynomial $f$ over $F$. Say $f=gh$ with $g,h$ being coprime. Let $F_g$ and $F_h$ be the splitting fields of $g$ and $h$ respectively. Is it true that $$\text{Gal}(E/F)\cong \text{Gal}(F_g/F)\times \text{Gal}(F_h/F)$$

Comment: What is $f$ isn't separable?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Take any two coprime polynomials with the same splitting field for a counter-example.

Examples:

- $x^2+1, x^2+4 \in \Bbb Q[X]$
- $x^p-t, x^p-t-1 \in \Bbb F_p(t)[X]$

Comment: But they are irreducible? And for the second you meant $\mathbb{F}_p(t)[X]$?

Comment: As examples of $g$ and $h$, i.e. $g=x^2+1$ and $h=x^2+4$.

Comment: You are right! I total agree with the first one. Why two from the second one have the same splitting field?

Comment: @CO2 if $x^p=t$, then $(x+1)^p=t+1$